# Obfuscating location?

Tags: mobile, data-collection, privacy

I have a webservice where I have one solution to obfuscate location called Points of interest which are predefined points scattered around an area.

When ever a user send their coordinates from their cellphone I calculate the Euclidean distance from their current location to the closest point of interest resulting in their location data is associated with the predefined point of interest.

This is fine, but I need one more way to obfuscate location.

What other options are there to obfuscate location?

Can I do something so simple as trimming the LatLng to two decimals?

How about adding noise to the coordinate data?

What type of noise can I use, will gaussian perturbation work?

I read about perlin noise https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Do You have any take on this?

Comment: What are you using the obfuscated data for? Why do you need to obfuscate it? How often are you updating the location? Given the update and identifiable data (e.g. general location or other attributes in combination including feasibility of solution), does it matter that locations might be obvious in any case?

Comment: What makes location special?  i.e. would a general solution to "how can I obfuscate information collected on a cellphone?" be sufficient?

Comment: To fit into this sites Q&A format, please consider splitting your thread into separate questions which can be answered individually.